# Creating a For loop to find sum of proper divisors

Tags: javascript

I have this problem for my CIS class: "Write a function named sumOfProperDivisors that accepts an integer n > 1, and returns the sum of the proper divisors of n.(A proper divisor is a positive divisor of a number, excluding the number itself. For example, 1, 2, and 3 are proper divisors of 6, but 6 itself is not.) Use a for loop, and use function expression syntax."

```
var sumOfProperDivisors = function(n > 1) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++)
```

Comment: Read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you want to find if the `n` parameter that you provided in the `function`  is divisible? You will need to edit your question & give more context so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// we don't have to search all numbers from 2 to the integer part of n / 2, 
// but from 2 to the integer part of the square root of n
// if n = 1000 we look for divisors in the interval [2, 31] and not in [2, 500]
const sumOfProperDivisors = n => {
  const root = Math.sqrt(n);
  let result = 1 + Number.isInteger(root) * root;
  for (let k = 2; k < root; k++) {
    if (n % k === 0) result += k + n / k;
  }
  return result;
}                 
console.log(sumOfProperDivisors(6));
console.log(sumOfProperDivisors(1000));
console.log(sumOfProperDivisors(1000000));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

- loop over from `i = 1` to `i = n/2` because once it cannot be divisible by something greater and n/2 and n.
- if the modulo (remainder) of n / i is zero then increment sum
- return sum

```js
function sumOfProperDivisors(n) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= n/2; i++){
    if (n % i == 0){
      sum++;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumOfProperDivisors(6))
```

Answer (score 0):

The laziest way to do this is loop through all the numbers before n, 1 to n-1
and check if the modulo of n with the number gives 0 that means n is divisible by that number then add that number to a variable "sum" each time the condition applies.
You can alter some details like looping from 1 to n/2 to remove unnecessary numbers.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a function, what goes in the parenthesis is the name of the argument, possibly with a default argument value, but the > 1 syntax you're using is not valid.

So, instead of:

```
function (n>1) {...}
```

You would need to do something like:

```
function (n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
    // ... throw an error or something...
    // or maybe you don't need to bother with this?
    // it's not super clear to me from the assignment
    }
```

The other thing I would point you to in order to answer your question is the modulo operator, which is the percent sign (%) in javascript. That operator will return the *remainder* of a division operator, so if you want to check if a number is divisible by another number, you can check if the remainder is 0 in this way...

```
if (3 % 2 === 0) { console.log('3 is divisible by 2')}
if (4 % 2 === 0) { console.log('4 is divisible by 2')}
if (5 % 2 === 0) { console.log('5 is divisible by 2')}
```

One final note: it's nice to write a bunch of tests for yourself to see how your function works and see if you understand it. So if I got this problem as homework, the first thing I might do is write a bunch of statements to test out my answer and see how they work...

For example:

    `console.log('sumOfProperDivisors(4) should be 3... and it is ',sumOfProperDivisors(4))
    console.log('sumOfProperDivisors(5) should be 1... and it is ',sumOfProperDivisors(5))
    console.log('sumOfProperDivisors(6) should be 6... and it is ',sumOfProperDivisors(6))
    console.log('sumOfProperDivisors(8) should be 7... and it is ',sumOfProperDivisors(8))`

Answer (score -1):

```
function findProperDivisor(num) {
if(num<0) return
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.floor(num / 2); i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      sum += i;

    }
  }
  return sum
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.